# Is this sentence correct: Use of 'Thank you.'

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I would be interested in your comments on the following sentence:

> Thank you for your assistance in this matter and we take this opportunity to send you our best wishes.

I can't explain why but it just sounds wrong to me.  I think it should either be:

> We thank you for your assistance in this matter and take this opportunity to send you our best wishes.

Or:

> Thank you for your assistance in this matter. We take this opportunity to send you our best wishes.

Comment: I agree. It's the issue of balance. 'Thank you for your assistance in this matter.' works fine as a fragment (there's essentially no verb), but coordinating it with an independent clause is inappropriate.

Comment: An analogous problem is found in: "Good job and I'd like to invite you to join the team."

Comment: I agree with your last two sentences for a few reasons. First, the express the subject. Second, in doing so, unity is added between the two clauses, which was not there in the first sentence since the subject of the first clause was orate.